# Best practice to store data in the database. Laravel and Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I'm developing an app using Laravel and Livewire, in which I have several post types, each one is store in the database using different views, because they differ in some fields, but in general are very similars. So I use one table to store them in the database.

The point is that I have one component (app/Http/Livewire/MyComponent.php & resources/views/livewire/my-component.blade.php) for each Post Type. In each one I have a method to store the data, but I know this is not the best way to do that.

I’ve been trying with Service Providers and Controllers, but not get the right way to do it.

The question is: What is the best way/practice to do this? Have a single class to store the data in the database, and call it from every where I need it.

Thanks you all.

**Edit:**

I have a class `App\Http\Livewire\Blog` to store Blog post type. Every thing works ok, but I want to put the method `store()` in a single class, and then call it from every Livewire's component class, because I store others post types in the same table in the database and I'm repeating the same code in every class for every component.

This is a simple example of my code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Blog;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\BlogPosts;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Post extends Component
{

    public $title, $content;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.blog.post');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = [
            'title'             => $this->title,
            'content'           => $this->content,
            'author'            => Auth::user()->id,
            'type'              => 'Blog Post',
            // Other data ...
        ];
        BlogPosts::create($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You show some codes of what you did ?

Comment: What have you tried? Did functional decomposition work for you already? How did creating the class you ask about worked out for you? Please elaborate by [edit], there is no better practice than your own, even if there would, answers merely based on opinion should not be asked for.

Comment: Do you have one model for each type also, or can you store them all via `Post::create(..)`?

Comment: @Qirel I have the same model for all post types